# Strange behaviour with UITextField and resigning first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my iOS application I have a form that the user fills out. I am using the return key on `UIKeyboard` to move to the next `UITextField` on screen.

So I implemented `textFieldShouldReturn` like this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(BBTextField *)textField
{
//The textFields are in a UITableView with custom cells///
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCellContaininView:textField];

    if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == SegmentedControlStep1){

            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                    switch (indexPath.row){
                        case 0:
                            [self.textFieldne becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            [self.textFieldTwo becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                    }
            }


            if (indexPath.section == 1){
                    switch (indexPath.row){
                        case 0:
                            [self.textFieldThree becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            [self.textFieldFour becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            [self.textFieldFive becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                    }
            }

            if (indexPath.section == 2){

                    switch (indexPath.row){
                        case 0:
                            [self.textFieldSix becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            [self.textFieldSeven becomeFirstResponder];
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            [self nextButtonPressed:nil];
                            break;
                    }
             }
    }

    if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == SegmentedControlStep2){

        switch (indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                [self.textFieldNine becomeFirstResponder];
                break;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This code works. However when `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called I then validate the input of some of the textfields and show a UIAlert on screen if the validation fails.

I handle that like this:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    /* Cancel registration */
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    /* Okay button */
    if (buttonIndex == 0){

            if (self.viewModel.telephoneNumberFailedValidation){

                        [self.textFieldOne becomeFirstResponder];

            }else if (self.viewModel.mobileNumberFailedValidation){

                        [self.textFieldTwo becomeFirstResponder];
            }
    }
}
```

So everything *appears* to work just fine up to this point. Once `UIAlertView` has been dismissed the following happens:

1. `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called (Expected and the text argument is nil ) - fine.
2. `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is called - (Expected as we are back on the textField that is now the first responder again )
3. `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called again on the textfield that has just become the first responder. And since the old failed text is still in the field, validation fails and we enter a constant loop.

Why is `textFieldDidEndEditing` being called twice?

Edit:

Stack trace from reference after `UIAlertView` has been dismissed:

[image]

Comment: have you looked at the stack trace. That might give you some clues as to what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, it shows UIKit calls to become / resign first responder. But from Apple's code. Not mine.

Comment: @villy393 I've updated the question with the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't figure out why `textFieldDidEndEditing` is being called twice  I decided to look at other  `UITextField delegate` methods that might be more appropriate and found this gem: `textFieldShouldEndEditing`- it asks if the `textField` *should* end editing. Seemed like the perfect place for my validation logic to go in. I simply return `NO` if validation fails and focus remains on the `UITextField` thus, there is no need for `UIAlertView's` `delegate` method: `clickedButtonAtIndex` - less code!

This `workaround` seems like the correct approach to my problem.